# If $\sum_{n=1} ^\infty a_{[f(n)]}$ converges, Then $\sum_{n=1} ^\infty f(a_n)$ converges,?

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, sequences-and-series

Our lecturer gave us this question after the class, and he said its a challenging one:

Let $a_n$ be a positive decreasing  sequence, And let $f(x)$ be a increasingly monotone function such that $f(x)\rightarrow \infty$.

Prove:
If $\sum_{n=1} ^\infty a_{[f(n)]}$ converges, Then $\sum_{n=1} ^\infty f(a_n)$ converges.

I have tried to prove it using the comprasion test, By trying to use $a_{f(n)}$ as a upper bound but failed.

How can I solve this question?
A full solution will be nice, but clues and hints very useful aswell.

Answer (score 4):

This is definitely false as stated. Take $f(x)=x^2+1$ and $a_n = \frac{1}{n}$ for each integer $n \ge 0$.

ETA: Even if you require $f(x)$ to be some nicely behaved function that goes to $0$ when $x$ goes to $0$, take $f(x) = x \times 2^x$, with $a_n = \frac{1}{n}$ as before.

Answer (score 1):

Suppose $\sum_na_n$ converges, $a_n$ non increasing and positive, $f:[0,\infty)\rightarrow(0,\infty)$ monotone increasing with $f(0)\geq1$. The series $\sum_n a_{\lfloor f(n)\rfloor}$ converges but $\sum_nf(a_n)$ does not since $f(a_n)\xrightarrow{n\rightarrow\infty}f(0)=1>0$.